# Running an array of TaskEithers in parallel, but continue if 1 or more task fails

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, fp-ts

I have to make an array of IO calls in parallel, and merge the contents of the call if successful. If one fails the others get processed as per normal, but an error message.

My thought process on how this can be implemented:

`Array<TE<E, A>> -> TE<E, Array<A>> -> TE<E, MergedA> -> [E, A]`

What I'm currently doing:

I am currently sequencing an array of TE, but any failure in the chain will yield a left.

```
pipe(
sequenceT(TE.taskEither)(arrayofTE), //TE<E,A>[] -> TE<E,A[]>
TE.map(mergeFn), //TE<E, A[]> -> TE<E, MergedA> 
???
)
```

How can I stop the short circuiting?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pass `T.task` instead of `TE.taskEither` to `sequence`/`sequenceT` ([docs](https://grossbart.github.io/fp-ts-recipes/#/async?a=comparison-with-promise-methods)):

> Action: execute an array of tasks in parallel, collecting all failures and successes
>
> TaskEither: **array.sequence(T.task)(taskEithers)** - same for **sequenceT**

#### [`sequence`](https://grossbart.github.io/fp-ts-recipes/#/async?a=work-with-a-list-of-tasks-in-parallel): Running tasks with same type in parallel

```
import { pipeable as P, taskEither as TE, task as T, array as A, either as E } from "fp-ts";

const arrayofTE: TE.TaskEither<string, number>[] = [
  TE.right(1),
  TE.right(2),
  TE.left("Oh shit")
];

const run = P.pipe(
  // change to T.task instead of TE.taskEither here
  A.array.sequence(T.task)(arrayofTE),
  mergeFn
);

run(); // run side effect
// returns Promise<{"errors":["Oh shit"],"results":[1,2]}>

// whatever merged result you want to have; this one collects all errors and all results
declare function mergeFn(te: T.Task<E.Either<string, number>[]>): T.Task<Results> 

type Results = { errors: string[]; results: number[] };
```

#### [`sequenceT`](https://grossbart.github.io/fp-ts-recipes/#/async?a=work-with-tasks-with-different-type): Running tasks with different type in parallel

```
import { apply as AP /* and others above */ } from "fp-ts";

// Here, TaskEither result can be number | boolean (success case), string on error
const arrayofTE = [TE.right(1), TE.right(true), TE.left("Oh shit")] as const;

const run = P.pipe(
  AP.sequenceT(T.task)(...arrayofTE), // we use sequenceT here and pass T.task again
  mergeFn
);

declare function mergeFn(a: T.Task<E.Either<string, number | boolean>[]>): T.Task<Results>
```

Here are sandboxes with `mergeFn` implementation to play around: [sequence](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-60471399-1?file=index.ts) , [sequenceT](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-60471399-2?file=index.ts).

Comment: thanks! That was exactly what I needed. The sequenceT on Tasks instead of TaskEithers did the trick. I should have been after a `TaskEither<E,A>[] -> Task<Either<E,A>>` instead of `TaskEither<E,A>[] -> TaskEither<E,A[]>`

Comment: Rather than needing to define your own `mapFn` you can also use [A.separate](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Array.ts.html#separate)

Comment: @harryg A.separate only works on `Either<left, right>`. So for the sequence version above you need the custom mapping fn

Answer (score 1):

sequenceT with fp-ts 2.16.1 where TE.taskStream is deprecated

```
import { sequenceT } from "fp-ts/lib/Apply.js"
import * as TE from "fp-ts/lib/TaskEither.js"

await pipe(
    sequenceT(TE.ApplyPar)(
      checkAuth(event),
      getDocs(event),
    ),
    TE.map(([auth, docs]) => {
      if (!auth) throw new Error("Unauthorized")
      return docs
    }),
    TE.map(flattenDocs),
)()
```